# Not able to find Endpoint URL and correct document for Sam.gov REST callout

Tags: labor

Not able to find any proper document for sam.gov REST API.
[Here](https://beta.sam.gov/entity/807849013?keywords=D%26B%20SUPPLY%20CO.&sort=-relevance&index=ei&is_active=true&page=1&date_filter_index=0&inactive_filter_values=false) is one example. I want the entire result in JSON or XML format so that I can use that in my system. I am not able to find the correct API URL for this.

Comment: Hi Tamil, I did a search on google with 'DOL REST API' and found https://www.programmableweb.com/api/us-department-labor ... is that what you are after??

Comment: @Tamil can you elaborate on this please? Are you saying that you cannot find documentation? Or that the API is not returning a proper document? Also, what have you tried? What are you trying to accomplish? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @MarcusD / albert, I have updated my comment.